# Blazor file input click not working in firefox

Tags: firefox, input, file-upload, click, blazor

I am creating a blazor application in which I am using the hidden file input and click() method to open the file picker. It works fine in Chrome, Edge. The file picker is not opening in Firefox.

Below is my sample code to reproduce the issue.
index.razor:

```
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime;
@*File Input is clicked using JSinterop on blazor click event of button*@
<div>
    <button @onclick="OnClick">Select File</button>
    <input type="file" id="fileElem" multiple style="display:none">
</div>


@code{
    private async Task OnClick()
    {
        //Triggers the click event of file Input
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("elementClick", "fileElem");
    }
}
```

JSInterop:

```
window.elementClick = (Id) => {
   // Triggers click event of the element
    document.getElementById(Id).click();
};
```

Is there any work around to resolve the above issue?

FireFox Version: 72.0.2

Update:  I have also reported this issue in [BUGZILLA](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1610726)

Comment: In firefox, click had no effect on file inputs, and it seems as though it still has no effect on file inputs.

Comment: Did you try to set breakpoint to `elementClick` function within Firefox? Does it get executed?

Comment: I checked the `elementClick` function with breakpoint in Firefox, it got executed. I also checked with custom function for onClick event of input. The custom function is executed, but the file picker is not opened. @VojtěchDohnal

Comment: So it seems it is rather a javascript Firefox problem not connected with blazor.

Comment: The same scenario works in firefox when I tried with plain Javascript and HTML @VojtěchDohnal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reported issue has been resolved in Firefox. Check the Bug Reports related to the issue below for your reference.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1610726

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1678389

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Seems to be a JsInterop related bug.

Created an issue in aspnetcore repo:
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/20228

**Workaround**:

Razor page:

```html
<input type="file" id="fileInput" style="display: none;" @onchange="YourAfterFileSelectedMethod"/> 
<button onclick="ClickFileInput()">Import</button>
```

Function:

```js
function ClickFileInput() {
    document.getElementById('fileInput').click();
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your workaround @xFirestrom. If ClickFileInput is in the javascript interop file, how can you directly call the function in click event?. If the function is defined in the razor page how can you use the document object on the razor page?  Correct me If I was wrong in understanding anything.

Comment: This button is not bind via blazor, there would be an @onclick. So the workaround is to use plain html and js to click the file input. I don't know why but doing it like that works. I mentioned the issue above, their are working on it and have it in their sprint planings for .NET 5